# "Variable \"$id\" of required type \"ID!\" was not provided."

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to query by passing the variable `id` in the query variable window.  This results in an error `"Variable \"$id\" of required type \"ID!\" was not provided."`

[image: a screenshot of GraphQL Playground]

When I run a different query without passing a variable in the query variable section it successfully returns results.

[image: a screenshot of GraphQL Playground]

Why does one produce an error, but not the other?

Answer (score 12):

You have to select the QUERY VARIABLES tab, and put the variable value there. You can check that in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that! It made me almost crazy. The distinction of the tabs between Query Variables and HTTP Headers is very bad and different from the tab type at the top side.

Answer (score 6):

In the first screenshot you've typed JSON into the "HTTP Headers" tab, not the "Query Variables" tab.  Clear out this section and type the JSON variables object into the correct tab.

Comment: I want to pass mutation input from query variable tab. How can I pass it without getting type error.

Comment: Thank you!  For some reason it never occurred to me that there was a difference...

Answer (score 0):

in my case i mistakenly provided query in `HTTP HEADERS` instead of `QUERY VARIABLE`,

provide values inside `QUERY VARIABLE` it solves your issues